# How can I use Base64 encoding in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64

I'm working in Base64 in Ruby on Rails and have a question:

For example how would the following be Base64 encoded / decoded?

```
<a href="myroute?id=<%=@client.id%>"> MY LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To create Base64 try this:

```
def create_base_64 
  begin 
    #for create 
    a = 1
    b = Base64.encode64(a.to_s)
    # for decoding
    c = Base64.decode64(b)
    puts c
  rescue Exception => e 
    puts e 
  end 
end
```

For more security try to broke it. For example:

```
b[1] = b[1] << SecureRandom.hex(1)
```

And other action, you recived the param b:

```
b = params[:b]
b[2]=""
b[2]=""
c = base64.decode64(b.to_s)
```

Comment: thanks, i work with example... but your broke the base64 and reassembled again the base64

Comment: do not rely on security through obscurity

Answer (score 8):

```
ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(`whateveryouwanttoencode`)
```

You don't really provide enough detail about what exactly you want to do. . .  The method I provided is how you accomplish Base64 encoding though, is that all you need?

Some documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveSupport/Base64

Comment: thanks, but first answer for @luis is interesting...per security

Comment: @pedroooo No problem, his post wasn't here when I was writing this.  Just trying to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: For me works just `Base64.encode64`, without `ActiveSupport`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying the achieve with your anchor tag example.  But to decode a base64 in ruby you would do this:

```
base64_string = "67382hfuisab3y289321787123890......"

decoded_data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(base64_string))
```

and then do whatever you want with decoded_data